# Import data of SQLite into in-memory database with Tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

How can I import data from the main database to the memory database?
I tried that, but Python raises this error. I did all I could to understand, but it doesn't work.

These functions show main data in the main Listbox:

```py
def clear_item_list():
    items.delete(0, END) # items is listbox

def fill_item_list(item):
    for item_ in item:
        items.insert(END, item_)

def item_list_view():
    clear_item_list()
    items = app.data_1.view()
    fill_item_list(items)
```

These functions show in-memory data:

```py
def clear_item_list_memory():
    item_list_user.delete(0, END) # item_list_user is listbox

def fill_item_list_memory(data):
    for item in data:
        print(data)
        item_list_user.insert(END, item)

def item_list_view_memory():
    clear_item_list_memory()
    items = app.user.memory.view()
    fill_item_list_memory(items)
```

This function imports the data and shows it in the in-memory database:

```py
def choose():
    clear_item_list_memory()
    item_memory = app.user.memory.insert(item_name.get(), numbers.get(), item_price.get())
    fill_item_list_memory(item_memory)
    item_list_view_memory()
```

And this is the full error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback   Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter&#95;_init__.py",
> line 1892, in __call__
> return self.func(*args)   File "D:\python\WindowsProject\app\user\user_sign_in.py", line 188, in
> choose
> fill_item_list_memory(item_memory)   File "D:\python\WindowsProject\app\user\user_sign_in.py", line 171, in
> fill_item_list_memory
> for item in data: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with tkinter because the error isn't caused by any of the tkinter code.

Comment: Check the value of `item_memory` (result of `app.user.memory.insert(...)`) to see whether it is what you expect.